# How to force overwriting ALL syntax highlighting in Vim?

Tags: syntax-highlighting, colorscheme

Recently, I have tried to create my own colorscheme in only one color and **no text decoration**. That means `Normal`, `Comment`, `ToolbarLine`, `Tooltip`... are the same; `Visual`, `Cursor`... are reversed, of course; no bold, no underline, no italic found.

Every built-in highlighting is successfully overwritten to one color, I pick **green color** for testing:
[image: Normal mode]

[image: Expected highlighting]

Because there are many unexpected name of highlighting, so there are **still some colorful highlighting**:

[image: Unexpected highlighting]

How to overwrite color for **not built-in** highlighting?

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]! I'm not quite sure I follow: you wanted to create a mono-chromatic colorscheme, so you highlighted the `highlight-default` groups. From there, you realized there were other groups that don't get overwritten, and you want to override those? Generally, you have to discover them and overwrite them. I wonder if you could do it programmatically, parsing the output of `:hi` or `:syn list`

Comment: Yes, you got my expectation. Is parsing the output the only way to solve my problem?

Comment: It's cleaner to use `getcompletion('', 'highlight')`. But, in general, color schemes should not touch such "user" groups at all. Note, for example, that you'll depend on the load order (color scheme vs. LightLine plugin).

Comment: Good call @Matt. ThinkMatic, you have other options (such as only touching the groups you care about). For example [this (horrible) colorscheme of mine](https://github.com/benknoble/zelda-vim/blob/master/colors/triforce.vim) just links syntax-related groups. [Dracula](https://github.com/dracula/vim) does something similar. [Thanks for reminding me I had left those zelda schemes unfinished lol]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try this vimscript (add to your vimrc and `call SetHLGreen()` function)

```
"" Get all highlights in a raw string
fun! GetHLStr()
    redir => all_hl
    highlight
    redir END
    return all_hl
endfun

"" Set all known highlight groups to green
fun! SetHLGreen()
    " get highlight groups without printing it in vim
    silent let hl_str = GetHLStr()

    " make list of highlight groups
    let hl_list = split(hl_str, '\n')

    " remove non highlight groups (parts of prev highlight group definition)
    call filter(hl_list, {_,v -> v !~ '^\s.*'})

    " extract just the highlight group names
    call map(hl_list, {_,v -> matchstr(v, '^\S\+')})

    " set all highlight groups foreground to "green"
    for hl_group in hl_list
        exe 'hi ' . hl_group . ' guifg=green ctermfg=green'
    endfor
endfun
```

PS, it looks like this:

[image]

PPS, it is even easier with `getcompletion` func (didn't know about it, thx @Matt)

```
"" Set all known highlight groups to green
fun! SetHLGreen()
    " set all of highlight groups to "green"
    for hl_group in getcompletion('', 'highlight')
        exe 'hi ' . hl_group . ' guifg=green ctermfg=green'
    endfor
endfun
```

Comment: What this is should be the default. You should have to do work to get it to have dinky colours. Thanks, Maxim, I am gonna do this myself.

Answer (score 0):

Most *filetypes* (like `python`) in Vim come with a syntax that defines highlight groups (see them via `:highlight python<C-d>`). These particular groups (e.g. `pythonFunction`) are then *linked* to a set of default groups (`:help highlight-groups`, e.g. `Identifier`). A *colorscheme* then provides combinations of foreground / background color and/or formatting like bold and italic (separately for terminals, color terminals, and/or GVIM) for the default groups.

*Plugins* are also encouraged to link to existing default groups; after all, these adhere to the user's preferred style and will work under whatever conditions (low-color / high-color terminal / GUI, bright / dark) the user has. However, some plugins either provide functionality that has no existing related concept in Vim, or they need a highlighting that is relatively independent of user choices (like red / green for test results; those should always look red / green even if the user prefers bluish hues).

So what you see is that *Lightline* plugin not linking to the default groups. That plugin should use [`:help :highlight-default`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/syntax.txt.html#%3Ahighlight-default), so you can override its custom definitions (with greenish ones) with `:highlight LightlineLeft_replace_1 ...` in your `~/.vimrc` (you can always *overwrite* them later, e.g. on `VimEnter`). Yes, that's a lot of definitions there (but apparently mostly combinations of a few base colors and text attributes, and you want just green, anyway), but this needs to be done only once, for this plugin and maybe a few more.

Alternatively, you could employ *meta-programming* and go over all `:hi` definitions *after* Vim startup (so plugins have added their definitions) and change them to green.